# Playing a Media File from Isolated Storage through MediaPlayer launcher in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am able to store media files into the Isolated Storage and able to retrieve the same.
Now what I want is to play the same media file through Media Player Launcher, I have tried using Media Element and I am able to play the stored media file but when I tried playing through Media Player launcher it gave me Argument Exception.

The Problem what I understood was that while retrieving the media file from Isolated Storage, it is returning in the form of "IsolatedFileStream".
You can set the media element source by the following method :

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile= IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream= storageFile.OpenFile(VideoFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        this.mediaElement.SetSource(fileStream); // Accepts IFileStream
    }
}
```

But there is no method to set the Media Property of the Media Player Launcher from Isolated Storage.

```
    MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher1 = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
    mediaPlayerLauncher1.Media = this.mediaElement.Source;// Argument Exception
    mediaPlayerLauncher1.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
    mediaPlayerLauncher1.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
    mediaPlayerLauncher1.Show();
```

Please provide me the way to sort this problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this code . 
it's very simple and work fine for IsoStorage files

```
MediaPlayerLauncher med = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
med.Media = new Uri("FileLocationInIsolatedStorage", UriKind.Relative);
med.Show();
```